# How to protect class to be instantiated directly

Tags: java, uml

How can I change this implementation:

```
public interface Animal()
{
   public void eat();
}

public class Dog implements Animal
{
   public void eat()
   {}
}

public void main()
{
   // Animal can be instantiated like this:
  Animal dog = new Dog();

  // But I dont want the user to create an instance like this, how can I prevent this declaration?
  Dog anotherDog = new Dog();
}
```

Comment: correction remove __()__ from __implements Animal(){__ i.e.  change **implements Animal(){** it to **implements Animal {**

Answer (score 7):

Create a factory method and protect the constructor:

```
public class Dog implements Animal {
   protected Dog () {
   }

   public static Animal createAsAnimal () {
      new Dog ();
   }
}
```

Comment: You probably would want to make the constructor `private` to forbid subclassing.

Comment: you are right Natix.

@Alexander Pogrebnyak, still we can keep the object type as Dog, can't we?!!! 

eg: __Dog anotherDog=....__

Comment: @Natix. OP did not state whether `Dog` should be subclassed, or not. I've assumed, that it may be, as OP did not declare it `final` in the example.  In case of a `final` `Dog` class, I would most definitely declare the constructor `private`

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak If you allow Dog to be subclassed, such as `class Hound extends Dog {}` then it is possible for the client to call `Dog dog = new Hound();` But if I think about it again, the original question doesn't really make much sense in its current form.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows by creating a factory method :

```
public interface Animal {
    public void eat();

    public class Factory {
    public static Animal getAnimal() {
        return new Dog();
    }
        private static class Dog implements Animal {
            public void eat() {
                System.out.println("eats");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Dog class is not visible to the user.
To run :

```
Animal dog= Animal.Factory.getAnimal();
dog.eat();//eats
```